# How to save particular object in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am facing some issue here i am try to store only one object either school or college or work, but mongoose automatically create other two object.

how to omit other object. here i should use `default`

```
let mySchema = new Schema({
    "type": { type: String, default: "" },  // school or college or work
    "school": {
        'name':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'parent':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'address':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'email_id':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'phone_no':{ type: String, default: "" },
    },
    "college": {
        'name':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'friend':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'address':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'email_id':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'phone_no':{ type: String, default: "" },
    },
    "work": {
        'name':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'colleague':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'address':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'email_id':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'phone_no':{ type: String, default: "" },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#subdocuments-versus-nested-paths) section from Mongoose docs, you will see that Mongoose always creates an empty object for nested documents (e.g. `school` in your case).

You could use a subdocument instead, where `school`, `college` and `work` are  instances of `Schema`.

What you can do:

```js
const mySchema = new Schema({
  school: new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    parent: { type: String },
    address: { type: String },
    email_id: { type: String },
    phone_no: { type: String },
  }),
  college: new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    friend: { type: String },
    address: { type: String },
    email_id: { type: String },
    phone_no: { type: String },
  }),
  work: new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    colleague: { type: String },
    address: { type: String },
    email_id: { type: String },
    phone_no: { type: String },
  }),
});
const MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', mySchema);
const myDocument = new MyModel();
myDocument.college = { name: 'Harvard' };
await myDocument.save();
```

Comment: There is any way to do with programmatically

Comment: @Dazil, I've edited my response with an example

Answer (score 0):

Is something avoiding you to set this programmatically?

```js
const myType = "school"; // Just for example

const mySchemaObj = { "type": { type: String, default: myType } };
mySchemaObj[myType] = { 
    "school": {
        'name':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'parent':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'address':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'email_id':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'phone_no':{ type: String, default: "" },
    },
    "college": {
        'name':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'friend':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'address':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'email_id':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'phone_no':{ type: String, default: "" },
    },
    "work": {
        'name':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'colleague':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'address':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'email_id':{ type: String, default: "" },
        'phone_no':{ type: String, default: "" },
    }
}[myType];

console.log(mySchemaObj);

/* Then, later...
let mySchema = new Schema(mySchemaObj);
*/
```

Comment: HI @Luka how can i set myType as dynamically?

Comment: Just like in the code snippet.